# How to remove IE pseudo-element appearing on the right edge of a textbox with password type?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element

I have a form with 2 text boxes representing username and password.

When typing in the text inside of the boxes I notice a `IE` specific pseudo-elements for Username and Password fields:

Username `textbox`:

```
<input class="form-control k-textbox checkError text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required=" " id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="username" type="text" value=""/>
```

Password `textbox`:

```
<input class="form-control k-textbox pwd text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-required=" " id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="password" type="password" value="" />
```

[image]

And there is the same one but for the `textbox` with a password type, only instead of 'X', there is kind of eye image.

I fixed the Username by having the following css code:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear
{
   display:none;
}
```

I thought that I can do the same for the password input field by using `type=password` line, but that did not fix the problem

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :ms-reveal

```
.form-control::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

complete list of ie specific pseudo elements present in the following link, which will come in handy

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869604(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I did by following already answered post